# 保護された質問を示す文章が英語のまま

Tags: バグ, 完了, 英語

[ボタンクリックの関数の処理が残ってしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29608/%e3%83%9c%e3%82%bf%e3%83%b3%e3%82%af%e3%83%aa%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%81%ae%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%81%8c%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86)

ここにComunityさんによって保護された質問がありますが、その事を示す文章が英語のままです。
リンク先の『信用度』『保護された質問について』(共にヘルプセンター)は日本語になっていますけど。

Comment: ありがとうございます。次回のビルドに適用します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transifex上](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/85812056?key=c77a336bf712ce9d05d6a30b151c5c68%7Cother)で翻訳しました。近日中に適用されるはずです。

Comment: 確認しました！ありがとうございます！